# Time Slider feature in ArcGIS 10.5 is displaying layer time extent to 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, data, format, timeslider

I've add a polygon shapefile that has a field that contains date and time in it's column.

However, when I attempt to calculate the layer time extent I'm getting the values of 1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM

[image]

Here is a screenshot of what I'm seeing. I've searched around and haven't really found anything specific on this item, like

[Time Slider in ArcMap 10 and Time Format Issues](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/13985/time-slider-in-arcmap-10-and-time-format-issues);
[Setting the time properties on data](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#/Setting_time_properties_on_data/005z0000000q000000/)

I'm sure it is something simple, but I thought I might put this out here to see if anyone may have encountered previously.

Comment: What date/times do your features have in their 'ShotDate' field?

Comment: It looks like the sample input above next to the time field drop down 2018/05/17 12:38:18'

Comment: Is that a string field?  Is there a space at the beginning of that value?  (Looks like it in the sample, but hard to be certain.)

Comment: Yes, it is a string field, no there is no space as the beginning.